Powershell-- how to add a variable's value into a filter?
I have this script where we have to manually change the computername prefix each time we run it at a different location
#you will need to change the site prefix from "xyz00" to whatever your site prefix is

$computers =  Get-ADComputer -filter {name -like "xyz00s*"}  |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name


The hostnames would be xyz00s1, xyz00s2, xyz00s3, etc. etc.  Always the site prefix followed by the letter s.
I would like to integrate a Read-Host into this but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.
$prefix =read-host "Enter the prefix of the site you are working on"

$computers =  Get-ADComputer -filter {name -like "$prefix + 's'*" }  |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

I've tried various combinations of " and ' and () and + and += etc.. Any guidance appreciated. I think it's because it's within the 'filter' that is causing the issues.

Have you tried $Filter = $prefix+'s*' and then use the variable in the filter?

Oh snap! No, but that seems to work!

AD filters are trial and error...

You should always avoid the scriptblock ({ .... }) in the -Filter parameter of ActiveDirectory Cmdlets. The parameter takes a string, so use one instead. If you want to interpolate $prefix in your filter you can use ${...} to indicate where the variable ends. See about_Variables for details.
$prefix = Read-Host 'Enter the prefix of the site you are working on'
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter "name -like '${prefix}s*'"

You can also use a sub-expression $(...):
$prefix = Read-Host 'Enter the prefix of the site you are working on'
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter "name -like '$($prefix + 's*')'"

